# How to get local time with NSDateFormatter (parsing from ICS file)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get the local time from an NSDate and it is only outputting the +0000 timezone. I'm parsing the information from an ICS file and then converting the string (looks like 20131001T114445Z) to a date with NSDateFormatter but for some reason I can't change it to the user's local time.

Here is the relevent code -

```
+(ISParseICS*) icsParser
{
    if( !fetcher ) {
        fetcher = [ISParseICS new];
        fetcher.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [fetcher.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd HHmmss"];

        NSLog(@"Created new singleton fetcher");
    }
    return fetcher;
}
```

Code below within -(NSMutableArray *)fetchPassesSync

```
// Extract date/time
        NSString *unformattedEndDateTimeString;
        NSDate *endDate;
        eventScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:event];
        [eventScanner scanUpToString:@"DTEND:" intoString:nil];
        [eventScanner scanUpToString:@"\n" intoString:&unformattedEndDateTimeString];

        unformattedEndDateTimeString = [unformattedEndDateTimeString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DTEND:"] withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"This is unformattedEndDateTimeString: %@", unformattedEndDateTimeString);
        endDate = [self dateFromString:unformattedEndDateTimeString];
        NSLog(@"End date - %@", endDate);
```

...and the last piece:

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString {

    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
    dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@""];
    NSDate *date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];


//    NSLog(@"The output date: %@", date);


    return date;
}
```

I'm pretty new to programming and I hope I asked the question correctly. Thanks in advance.

Edit: What I get out of all this code is it takes the string "20131001T114445Z" and outputs like this "2013-10-01 11:44:45 +0000"

Comment: try using like this [fetcher.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

Comment: Doesn't that `z` mean "zulu time" (i.e. GMT + 0000)?

Comment: @Shan yep, thanks I got it all figured out. Thanks!

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, z means zulu/+0000 - I finally got it figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 NSString *dateStr = @"20131001T114445Z";

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'Z'"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];
    dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateStr);
    [dateFormat release];
```